# Tower Law and normal field extensions

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, extension-field

The question is, if L\K and M\L are normal field extensions then is M\K normal? The answer is false, however, I am not sure how they have got to this, I understand the Tower law to be;

[M:K]=[M:L][L:K]

How would I use this to get false? please may you also give an example, I am studying for my finals and would like as much help as appreciated.

Comment: Just because the dimension is multiplicative, why should this mean that normality also behaves this way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the tower $\mathbb Q\subset \mathbb Q(\sqrt{2})\subset \mathbb Q(\sqrt[4]{2})$.

The first extension is the splitting field of $x^2-2$ and the second is the splitting field of $x^2-\sqrt{2}$ so they are both normal extensions. But the $\mathbb Q$-polynomial $x^4-2$ has some roots in the top extension but not all. For example none of the non-real roots of this polynomial are in the top field.